# Folder-wise RAID1 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Don't know what else to call it, so humour me and feel free to provide better terminology.

Anyway, I'm looking for a way to mirror a folder - and a folder only.
I.e. whatever I do to the files in folder A on disk0 should be reflected in folder B on disk1 without my having to manually invoke a backup command. (Otherwise I could just as well copy-paste changes.)

Does Win7 provide such a functionality?
And if not, do you have any software recommendations?

Comment: I would just use file synchronizing software. A RAID solution isn't the proper solution for the problem you describe

Comment: No, RAID is a disk/volume phenomena, and does not know or care about filesystem stuff like directories. you will need to use a synch utility like the MS SynchToy, but it will not be constantly watching your foldes: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True  you will have to schedule it or invoke it from a script. There are several dotnet objects like FileSystemWatcher that you can implement in a power shell script to launch synchs as needed, but you'll have to write it yourself or find one online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments mention above software is the way to go not hardware.... Allway Sync I've used for this and is very good!

http://allwaysync.com/